# C++ Send bytes from a string?

Tags: c++, string

I am writing a little program that talks to the serial port. I got the program working fine with one of these lines;

```
unsigned char send_bytes[] = { 0x0B, 0x11, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x69, 0x85, 0xA6, 0x0e, 0x01, 0x02, 0x3, 0xf };
```

However the string to send is variable and so I want make something like this;

```
char *blahstring;
blahstring = "0x0B, 0x11, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x69, 0x85, 0xA6, 0x0e, 0x01, 0x02, 0x3, 0xf"
unsigned char send_bytes[] = { blahstring };
```

It doesn't give me an error but it also doesnt work.. any ideas?

Comment: what? 0x0B is not the same as "0x0B".  what are you trying to do exactly?  what function are you using to send?

Comment: You'll need to write a function to parse that string. Split it at each comma and convert from hex. You'll need to count the number of bytes as well. And use `std::string` for both the input and the output because it will bundle the length in for you. (Or follow Aniket's answer.)

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html may help. You can split your string, do a `lexical_cast<int>` then cast the int to an `unsigned char`

Answer (score 7):

a byte-string is something like this:

`char *blahString = "\x0B\x11\x00\x02\x00\x69\x85\xA6\x0E\x01\x02\x03\x0f"`

Also, remember that this is not a regular string. It will be wise if you explicitly state it as an array of characters, with a specific size:

Like so:

```
unsigned char blahString[13] = {"\x0B\x11\x00\x02\x00\x69\x85\xA6\x0E\x01\x02\x03\x0f"};
unsigned char sendBytes[13];
memcpy(sendBytes, blahString, 13); // and you've successfully copied 13 bytes from blahString to sendBytes
```

not the way you've defined..

EDIT:
To answer why your first `send_bytes` works, and the second doesn't is this:
The first one, creates an array of individual bytes. Where as, the second one, creates a string of ascii characteres. So the length of first `send_bytes` is 13 bytes, where as the length of the second `send_bytes` is much higher, since the sequence of bytes is ascii equivalent of individual characters in the second `blahstring`.

Comment: Your code works fine.. however when I change the blahString to blahstring[13] = { cmdstring }; it doesnt work anymore. cmdstring is; char cmdstring ={"\x0B\x11\x00\x02\x00\x69\x85\xA6\x05\x00\x00\x70" }; Any ideas?

Comment: you shouldn't do that @AlexvanEs instead just use `memcpy()` to copy from one string to another. See my answer(see where I use `memcpy`). Also `cmdstring` is not a character, its a `char *`

Answer (score 0):

`blahstring` is a string of characters.

1st character is 0, 2nd character is x, 3rd character is 0, 4th character is B etc. So the line

```
unsigned char send_bytes[] = { blahstring };
```

is an array (assuming that you preform a cast!) will have one item.

But the example that works is an array with the 1st character has a value 0x0B, 2nd character is of value 0x11.